# In Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis, what is the difference between the Wits, Fists and Team paths?

Tags: indiana-jones-fate-of-atlantis

In the middle of Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis, I'm given the choice of three paths that I can proceed down: Wits, Fists and Team.

- Are the three paths significantly
  different?
- Is one path easier than
  the others?
- Do all of the paths
  lead to the same ending?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've played through the game multiple times in all three paths.

While you do pretty much visit the same areas in all three paths, you do completely different things in each, which, in my opinion, warrant three separate playthroughs.  Just save right at the decision time and you can easily do all three.

I personally don't think any path is significantly easier than any others, but I do think that Wits is definitely the hardest.  If I had to rank them, I'd say Wits is the hardest, followed by Team, followed by Fists.

All three paths converge before you get to Atlantis and end exactly the same.

Comment: The fists path is easier because of the "cheat" punch.  I would guess that by not using the one-punch technique would make this path much harder to complete.

Answer (score 6):

I've only played on Wits, so I'm going off what I'm reading online right now.

The three paths differ primarily in how you accomplish different goals, and some of the scenarios around them. They do converge at a later point in the game. You will get the same locations in each one, but apparently under different circumstances, and it looks like different interactions with the other characters of the game.

According to the [Indiana Jones Wiki](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Fate_of_Atlantis):

> It is at this point that the player has to choose between either the Team Path, in which Indy continues on with Sophia and the game consists mostly of puzzles involving tag teaming with her, the Fists Path, in which Indy goes alone and the game involves lighter puzzles and more fighting, or the Wits Path, in which Indy goes alone and there are harder puzzles and less fighting.